# MySQL8.0の行ロックの仕様について

Tags: mysql

MySQL8.0にて、`SELECT...FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`で行ロックを取得しようとした際、SELECTが空振りした際にもギャップロックがかかる認識で、`performance_schema.data_locks`にもレコードが追加されていることを確認したのですが、エラーになることを期待して別セッションで同じ条件の`SELECT...FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`を実行した際にエラーにならずロックがとれてしまいました(`performance_schema.data_locks`にレコードが増えた)。

この時、後続のセッションで期待通りのエラーを起こすための手段があればご教示いただきたきたいです。

質問の背景
DBにアクセスしてデータをINSERTするアプリを作成しており、AUTO_INCREMENTが使えない状況下で並列でINSERTされることを想定して、事前に`SELECT...FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`で行ロックをかけて、ロックされていればアプリ側でエラーハンドリングするような設計をしていました。

Comment: トランザクション分離レベルによると思いますが、SELECT...FOR UPDATEを発行しただけでは、読み取りにロックはかからないのではないでしょうか？INSERTした瞬間に待ち合わせが発生しますが、本当に同時に実行された場合、SELECTは双方通過してしまうので、DEADLOCKになるだけだと思います。INSERTのみなら、COMMITした瞬間に片方だけ成功します。

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## 回答ではありません。

(なので最も役に立つ回答などではないのでご注意を)
コメントに書いたDEADLOCKの件の現象確認用スクリプトです。

```bash
cat >docker-compose.yml <<EOF
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
EOF
docker compose up -d
docker compose exec -T db bash <<EOF
while ! mysql --password=example </dev/null 2>/dev/null; do
    sleep 1
done
mysql --verbose --password=example <<EOF2
-- drop database hoge;
create database hoge;
use hoge;
create table hoge(
id varchar(100) primary key,
value numeric
);
EOF2
EOF
docker compose exec -T db bash <<EOF &
mysql --verbose --table --database=hoge --password=example <<EOF2
select version();
begin;
set profiling=1;
select * from hoge where id='1' for update nowait;
select sleep(3);
insert into hoge values('1', 1);
commit;
show profiles;
EOF2
EOF
docker compose exec -T db bash <<EOF &
mysql --verbose --table --database=hoge --password=example <<EOF2
select version();
begin;
set profiling=1;
select * from hoge where id='1' for update nowait;
select sleep(3);
insert into hoge values('1', -1);
commit;
show profiles;
EOF2
EOF
wait
docker compose down
```

実行結果

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network tmp_default  Created                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 ✔ Container tmp-db-1   Started                                                                                                                                                         1.4s 
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
--------------
-- drop database hoge;
--------------

--------------
create database hoge
--------------

--------------
create table hoge(
id varchar(100) primary key,
value numeric
)
--------------

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
--------------
select version()
--------------

+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.2.0     |
+-----------+
--------------
begin
--------------

--------------
set profiling=1
--------------

--------------
select * from hoge where id='1' for update nowait
--------------

--------------
select sleep(3)
--------------

+----------+
| sleep(3) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
--------------
insert into hoge values('1', 1)
--------------

ERROR 1213 (40001) at line 6: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
--------------
select version()
--------------

+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.2.0     |
+-----------+
--------------
begin
--------------

--------------
set profiling=1
--------------

--------------
select * from hoge where id='1' for update nowait
--------------

--------------
select sleep(3)
--------------

+----------+
| sleep(3) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
--------------
insert into hoge values('1', -1)
--------------

--------------
commit
--------------

--------------
show profiles
--------------

+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                             |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.01331375 | select * from hoge where id='1' for update nowait |
|        2 | 3.00098250 | select sleep(3)                                   |
|        3 | 0.04366000 | insert into hoge values('1', -1)                  |
|        4 | 0.00948575 | commit                                            |
+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container tmp-db-1   Removed                                                                                                                                                         2.3s 
 ✔ Network tmp_default  Removed
```

---

どういう理由でわざわざマイナス評価をしたのか知りませんが、別に手段があれば修正しますので、意図を明確にしてください。

回答ではないと書いてるのに回答でないからマイナス評価だとすると、他に手段がないので仕方ないです。コメント欄にコードなどを記載出来ればいいのですけどStackoverflowではそれが出来ないので。何か私が勘違いしてることなどあれば教えて頂けないと気付けません。言い争いをして意味不明な通報から削除されると却って意味が分からなくなりますが、私はきちんと意味のある話しかしないので、堂々と主張してください。

Comment: 私はこの投稿に投票していませんが、もしこの投稿が回答でないならば、回答として投稿しないでください。回答になっていない回答は削除対象です。コメントにコードブロックを書けないのは意図的な設計です。もしこの設計にご意見がありましたら [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) までお寄せください。また、一応、本当にコメントの用途として長めのコードが必要なのであれば、チャットを利用するか、https://pastebin.com/ などの外部サービスを利用することはできます。

Comment: 別に回答でないと書いてあるので問題ありません。外部リンクは有名でないと広告と区別が付かず、有名なものは時限式が多いので回答欄が妥当です。チャットについては知りませんが、コードが書けるのでしょうか？また書いたものはクリックせずに他の人がすぐ見れますか？Metaな内容に意見とか面倒すぎてする気はありません。ただの利用者なので。

Comment: 回答でないと書いてあっても削除対象です。スタック・オーバーフローは掲示板ではなく、質問と回答の距離を近くするために質問と回答のみを目立つ場所に集めています。

Comment: 削除対象かどうかは問題ではありません。ルールというのは人間のためにあります。無駄なことや私用などで使われているなら削除の必要があるが、無秩序ではまずいというだけですよ。何のためにモデレーターなどというものがあるのか考えたことはないのですか？

Comment: このサイトのルールについて問題提起がなさりたいのであれば[メタ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)までお越しください。

Comment: 再度言いますが、Metaな内容に意見とか面倒すぎてする気はありません。ただの利用者なので。このサイトのルールが具体的にどうとかは関係なく、人間社会のルールというは人間のためにあるというだけです。

Comment: @dameo さん、質問者さんには有用な情報として承認されたようなので、質問に付けたコメントの続きや具体例として回答されたのであれば、コメントの内容を回答記事に統合して回答単体として意味を成す様に改善してみてはどうでしょう？ ついでに提示されたスクリプトで現象確認された後に何か行うべきことや注意点などがあれば追記しておくとより良い情報共有になると思われます。

Comment: 質問者さんが何を考えて解決としたかは謎です。また、私が回答を控えている理由は回答に必要な情報が足りていないからです。私に何かすべきことがあるとは思っていないので、質問者さんは有限な時間を自分のために使えばいいでしょう。逆にコメントするなら具体的にしないと時間を無駄にしますよ。